# Create a date flag column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a Date Flag column based on 2 date columns. I would like the date flag to be structured such that the column value = 1 on the first instance that Date Column 2 is greater than Date Column 1. All other values in the date flag column should be 0. I have attached a screenshot.

I have tried a case statement as follows:

```
select DateColA, DateColB, case when DateColB > DateColA then 1 else 0 end as DateFlag
from table_A
order by DateColA
```

However, this makes all rows where DateColB > DateColA = 1 in the DateFlag column. I only want the first one.

Comment: Ambiguous at best...  The first one what?  Perhaps it would be best if you provide some sample data and desired results (as text)

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, in **consumable** formats will help us help you. There is no image in your question, and ev n if there was, it would not be helpful. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Fyi `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with a *windowed* `COUNT()` function combined with *conditional aggregation* and a test for `COUNT(...) = 1` to select the first eligible row.

Logic:

- A slightly modified version of your original test is wrapped up in a `COUNT()` function using a technique called *conditional aggregation*. The `ELSE 0` portion is omitted so that only the `THEN 1` values are counted. The *implied* `ELSE NULL` is not counted.
- The `COUNT()` is made into a *window* function by adding `OVER(ORDER BY DateColA)`. This form of the `OVER` clause will produce a running count of the eligible rows.
- Finally, we test for that running count `= 1` combined with the original test to select just the first eligible row.

```
select
    DateColA, DateColB,
    case when DateColB > DateColA then 1 else 0 end as DateFlag0,
    count(case when DateColB > DateColA then 1 end)
         over(order by DateColA)
         as DateFlag0Count,
    case when DateColB > DateColA
         and count(case when DateColB > DateColA then 1 end)
                  over(order by DateColA) = 1
         then 1 else 0 end 
         as DateFlag
from table_A
order by DateColA
```

Sample results:

| DateColA | DateColB | DateFlag0 | DateFlag0Count | DateFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024-01-03 | 2024-01-04 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-01-04 | 2024-01-04 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2024-01-05 | 2024-01-06 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2024-01-06 | 2024-01-06 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2024-01-07 | 2024-01-10 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-01 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 2024-01-09 | 2024-01-10 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 2024-01-10 | 2024-01-10 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

Where:

- DateFlag0 is your original calculation,
- DateFlag0Count is the running count of eligible rows, and
- DateFlag is the desired result.

(The DateFlag0 and DateFlag0Count columns are present for demo purposes only.)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3jKDYXmT).